# Usage of "Who" and "whom" in the given sentence

Tags: word-usage

In the given sentence,"There’s Mr. Som, who they say is the best singer in the country" is "who" is the correct word to be used or "whom"

Comment: @MattЭллен Yes, but this particular example is ambiguous. *Who* appears to refers to the object of *they say* (and should therefore be *whom*) but re-arranging the sentence makes "They say he is the best singer" (so it's *who*). I'm sure this sort of conundrum has appeared here before, but it's not the question you have nominated and I can't find the right one.

Comment: @Andrew: Not to mention that the sentence could be punctuated "There’s Mr. Som, who, they say, is the best singer", in which case the answer is clearly "who".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misconceived issue -- there's no ambiguity -- NARQ. 

Comment: @Andrew I'll give you that this is a garden-path sentence, but other than that that's clutching at straws. Once you arrive at *is*, it becomes clear that *who* clearly isn't the object of *they say* here. For that, the sentence would have to be "There's Mr. Som whom they say to be". The older question covers this just fine. "Whom is" is *never* grammatical. The "they say" is a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

Geoffrey Pullum has given this question his full consideration [on Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4342).

Here’s his conclusion:

> It's the neatest case I know of in which a dispute about what's
>   correct turns out to have no possible resolution, because there are
>   two perfectly defensible rules that have slightly different
>   consequences, and the evidence from literature says that different
>   writers make different choices of rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use the he/him method to decide which word is correct.

he = who
him = whom

> Who/Whom wrote the letter?

*He* wrote the letter. Therefore, *who* is correct.

> For who/whom should I vote?

Should I vote for *him*? Therefore, *whom* is correct.

> We all know who/whom pulled that prank.

This sentence contains two clauses: 
*We all know* and *who/whom pulled that prank.*

We are interested in the second clause because it contains the *who/whom. He* pulled that prank. Therefore, *who* is correct. (Are you starting to sound like a hooting owl yet?)

> We want to know on who/whom the prank was pulled.

This sentence contains two clauses: 
*We want to know* and *the prank was pulled on who/whom.* 
Again, we are interested in the second clause because it contains the *who/whom.* 
The prank was pulled *on him.* 
Therefore, *whom* is correct.

Now...

Consider the following sentence:

> Who do you consider the best composer?

Should it be *who* or *whom*?

Figure it out by turning the sentence around and replacing the *who* or *whom* with *he* or *him*. If *he* is wrong, so is *who*. If *him* is wrong, so is *whom*.

Do you consider him the best composer?
*Do you consider he the best composer?

Since *him* is correct, use *whom*. *Whom* do you consider the best composer?

> It was Corelli, you’ll find, who composed that piece.

Turning the sentence around, which is correct?

*He* composed that piece.
**Him* composed that piece.

Since *he* is correct, use *who* in the sentence.

Comment: I *think* this is now easier to read and sort out examples from their discussion. However, what is the answer to the question? (See my comment on the question itself)

Comment: I suggest you read Geoffrey Pullum's post on Language Log, VB.